# Custom css only for one content type

Tags: 8, theming

I want to include custom css only for one content type, is that possible?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets this may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets such as CSS and JavaScript files are added via the asset management system.

There are three types of assets libraries settings & replacements.

What you need is a library asset that will include your CSS files.

Adding assets is done by setting the #attached array in a render array.
That way you can *attach* the asset only when the render array is rendered.

Because you do not control the render array of nodes, you will need to implement `hook_page_attachments` and add your library on your specific conditions.

### foo.libraries.yml

```
bar:
  css:
    component:
      css/baz.css: {}
```

### foo.module

```
foo_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  if (/*CONDITION*/) {
    $attachments['#attach']['library'][] = 'foo/bar';
  }
}
```

Comment: Libraries can also be added in twig templates (e.g. node--page.html.twig), with `{{ attach_library('module/library') }}` or `hook_preprocess_node()` by adding to `$variables['#attached']['library']`.  Probably better to target a node with these than with `hook_page_attachments()`

Comment: @gapple i think preprocess functions are too late for #attached. But I'll add the twig option.

Answer (score 1):

use **node-type-"node-type-machine-name"** class from body, it appears in body, and then apply inherited CSS on child classes or on elements. e.g. if you are using a content type conference use

```
.note-type-conference{ 
//style
}
```

or

```
.note-type-conference .any-other-child-class{ 
    //style
    }
```

open your developer console of browser and check body element it contains many unique and specific classes.